# TYPO3 "Core: Error handler (FE): PHP Warning: is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper ..."

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am learning to use TYPO3. I have installed TYPO3 v6.2.4 and "The official Introduction Package" on Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS. All worked fine, but one morning I've noticed that my TYPO3 site loads very long time. And after that it looks weird (it seems that css is missing). First of all I logged to TYPO3 CMS Backend and saw in the Log the following:

```
Core: Error handler (FE): PHP Warning: is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper &quot;ttp&quot; - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in /opt/typo3/typo3_src-6.2.4/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php line 884
```

[GeneralUtility.php line 884](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/e1023efd70d1ef36f90c0e36381d1f439cc1557f/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php#L884)

After googling for a while, I didn't  find exact answer what this error is. I tried to find the reason myself. Luckily after clearing cache by pressing "Flush general caches" my site started to work correctly. But next morning the situation was repeated.

It would be nice to find the reason of error, but I don't know where to start. Currently I am reading "[Efficiently Debugging TYPO3](http://wiki.typo3.org/Efficiently_Debugging_TYPO3)". Maybe someone faced this situation or can give good advice how to solve it. Thanks.

p.s. Sorry, English isn't my native language, probably I made a lot of mistakes in the text )

Answer (score 1):

While this is not directly an answer, we experience the same warnings. Though I also have no clue where this is coming from.

→ At the given log times, there are entries in the access logs, but not with "ttp" scheme. Though, the referrer `http://httpheader.net` is strange. I anonymized the IP in the log lines. For today, there are two accesses 10 secs apart. Note that this results in a 307 redirect, but the client did not follow that as there are no follow up entries. To me, seems to be a bot causing this.

`93.174.0.0 - - [15/Sep/2014:06:58:57 +0200] "GET http://www.fsmb.de/ HTTP/1.1" 307 267 "http://httpheader.net" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.28) Gecko/20120306 Firefox/3.6.28 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
93.174.0.0 - - [15/Sep/2014:06:58:47 +0200] "GET http://www.fsmb.de/ HTTP/1.1" 307 267 "http://httpheader.net" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.28) Gecko/20120306 Firefox/3.6.28 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"`

→ In our whole project structure, including typo3 sys folder, vendor folders, own extensions, static Typoscript, a regex search for `[^h]ttp` remains effortless.

→ In the whole DB, a regex search for `[^h]ttp` remains effortless.

My conclusion this far is, that probably the ttp scheme is not caused by a typo as discussed in http://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/205719/, but maybe some substring-index or regex-splitting related problem with normal URLs. We should check the context of all usages of `GeneralUtility::split_fileref`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am using typo3 4.7, and there in my logs it says

```
Core: Error handler (FE): PHP Warning: is_dir(): Unable to find the wrapper "ttp" -
     did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? 
    in typo3_src-4.7.10/t3lib/class.t3lib_div.php line 1005
```

I've looked it up in file `class.t3lib_div.php`, and the function that creates this error is called `split_fileref()`

```
     /**
      * Splits a reference to a file in 5 parts
      *
      * @param string $fileref Filename/filepath to be analysed
      * @return array Contains keys [path], [file], [filebody], [fileext     ], [realFileext]
      */
     public static function split_fileref($fileref) {
     //[...]
     if (!is_dir($fileref) && preg_match('/(.*)\.([^\.]*$)/', $info['file'], $reg))         $info['filebody'] = $reg[1];
     }
         //[...]
```

So I suspect somewhere in one of your typo3 content elements someone has entered an URL where a path should be.

But how to find this misconfigured page in the backend? I have no idea. I can also be several pages.

And that does not necessarily mean that this is the definite cause of your performance problems.